# Git: what is the meaning of --first-parent and how does it change the output of rev-list?

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand the difference between doing a `git rev-list --count HEAD`
with and without `--first-parent`.

The Git documentation says this:

> --first-parent
>   Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This option can give a better overview when viewing the
>   evolution of a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic
>   branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time
>   to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual commits
>   brought in to your history by such a merge. Cannot be combined with
>   --bisect.

but with my current knowledge of Git it is still not clear what is the difference between `git rev-list --first-parent --count HEAD` and `git rev-list  --count HEAD`.

I'm trying to count the number of commit in my master branch to use it as version code (must be an integer number bigger than the previous build, if there are new commits) for an Android application.

Should I use `--first-parent` or not?

Comment: `--first-parent` has to do with the traversal of the commit graph. How much do you know of graph theory? :-)

Comment: @torek Probably not enough :-) but can the count be different if I use that option? Or no matter what it will be the same?

Comment: It will vary, depending on the graph. What `--first-parent` does is limit the graph traversal every time Git reaches a merge commit. See http://think-like-a-git.net/ or my extremely draft-y book draft at http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The count is different. Here below you have a git log whose HEAD is `A` and arrows represents parents. The path made only by following first parents is denoted by `=>`, whereas other parents are indicated by `->`.

```
(head) A ==> B ==> C ==> D ... 
              \                 
               \--> E --> F ...
```

Does it matter to you? The only thing you need is to be *consistent* in your numbering scheme. Note that in both cases, with first parents or not, the resulting number does not uniquely identify your version. You could have different branches with the same version just because they contain the same number of commits.